# How to Remove index.php from second project of CodeIgniter when two project are in same directory?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have two project of CODEIGNITER in my single Directory, to remove the index.php from the URL i have add the file .htaccess in my root folder but when i m running the both projects the first one is running through CONTROLLER while second one is giving me 404 page not found error.
 my .htaccess file code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have two project in one directory and the code in my .htaccess is check below, try it and see if it work for you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     Options -Indexes
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```